# Error en PHPMailer

Tags: php, html, formularios

Holaa, estoy intentando hacer que cuando un usuario haga click en el button para enviar un formulario le llegue vía e-mail una notificación a modo de que hemos recibido correctamente su solicitud. He intentado hacerlo mediante PHPMailer, pero al compilar da el siguiente error:
ACTUALIZACIÓN:

> Message could not be sent. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed

Dejo aquí los codes: (la información está rellenada con los datos default)
Form PHP:

```
 require("./mailer/src/PHPMailer.php");
  require("./mailer/src/SMTP.php");
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {   
        $email = $_POST['email'];
$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
$mail->Host = 'smtp1.example.com;smtp2.example.com';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = 'user@example.com';                 // SMTP username
$mail->Password = 'secret';                           // SMTP password
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';                            // Enable encryption, 'ssl' also accepted

$mail->From = 'from@example.com';
$mail->FromName = 'Mailer';
$mail->addAddress($email);
$mail->addReplyTo('info@example.com', 'Information');
$mail->addCC('cc@example.com');
$mail->addBCC('bcc@example.com');

$mail->WordWrap = 50;                                 // Set word wrap to 50 characters
$mail->addAttachment('/var/tmp/file.tar.gz');         // Add attachments
$mail->addAttachment('/tmp/image.jpg', 'new.jpg');    // Optional name
$mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML

$mail->Subject = 'Here is the subject';
$mail->Body    = 'This is the HTML message body <b>in bold!</b>';
$mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo 'Message has been sent';
}
}
```

Comment: Instalaste phpmailer con composer ??

Comment: @Excorpion no, descargándolo manualmente y añadiéndolo por includes

Comment: No estás incluyendo el script con la clase `Exception`, deberías tener algo como `require './mailer/src/Exception.php';` que no va a hacer funcionar el envío de correo, pero debería darte un mensaje de error adecuado para saber lo que está mal.

Comment: @Triby Me da error de conexión del smtp, actualizo la pregunta con el nuevo error

Comment: Pues eso, la conexión a ese servidor, con esos datos de conexión, falla. Corresponde verificar que sean correctos. Ver si smtp.example.com se autentica tls, si el usuario es correcto, si la contraseña es correcta... (supongo que example.com son datos falsos para publicar la pregunta...)

Comment: Gracias! Acabo de resolverlo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para ver el error concreto añadimos al code:

```
require './mailer/src/Exception.php';
```

Por si a alguien más le pasa que le da error al conectar el smtp, probad a cambiar la propiedad "SmtpSecure" a tls, quedaría algo así:

```
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
```